# Query to get the latest data of a group by data in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I have a SQL table where I am trying to extract the latest data for each category.

My table schema

```
| deviceId                    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rssi                        | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| space_temperature           | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| control                     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| counter                     | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp                   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date                        | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| floor                       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Id                          | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I want to fetch the latest row for each Id.

```
select * from Data where floor = 'L2' and date = '2019-12-10' group by Id;
```

This is giving me a row for each Id, but it is giving me the first entry but not the latest entry in the table.

I tried with

```
select *,max(timestamp) as latest_timestamp from Data where floor = 'L2' and date = '2019-12-10' group by Id;
```

This is giving the latest timestamp but the other columns have the data of the first entry. How to get the results of the latest entry for each Id group?

Comment: Give some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way -

```
select * from Data a where floor = 'L2' and date = '2019-12-10'
and timestamp =(select max(timestamp) from data b where a.id=b.id)
```

Comment: I am trying to run this query, its taking forever to run. Will adding indexes help ?